# How to insert JSON string to mysql with node.js script?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, json

I have a string like this:

```js
{
  WABrowserId: '"hTCl7asDPe/EIymrQC57Hg=="',
  WASecretBundle: '{"key":"o65mhfj8XZpuCIIgamAdsaibobs0HKiiBCwTAn36qms=","encKey":"nw5vM2sa05Eh94boiPO5r2qi5fS7CZmJwNNWgIsEj08=","macKey":"o65mhfj8XZpuCIIgamAd3Eibobs0HKiiBCwTAn36qms="}',
  WAToken1: '"ArRasrW9r63ByrbKDAauchBnzEUYOO9q0HTWJYfG0RM="',
  WAToken2: '"1@GGZtYQss1DkFVbXvuH28Dmm6YdI6wkHvqN1lSbAVAj+S4N5g3qQwuEAdQBsEp/j1cPVRu4bMexECrQ=="'
}
```

I got an error message like this:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`WABrowserId` = '"hTCl7AYDPe/EIymrQC57Hg=="', `WASecretBundle` = '{"key":"o' at line 1

How can I insert this string into a MySQL database with a Node.js script?

Comment: One approach is convert the JSON string to base64 and then save to database as plain text.

Comment: You need to post your code. I suspect you're concatenating the JSON into the query, rather than using placeholders.

Comment: Your JavaScript object needs to be serialized into actual JSON, before you save it off to the database. Try to call `JSON.stringify(obj)` first.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid from MySQL looking point. Remove all single quotes.

Comment: thanks for your solution all, i resolve my problem now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert normal JS object, you need to parse into JSON using `JSON.stringify(obj)` function then insert into the database.

you might also need to remove the single quotes and use double quotes.